# Is it possible to solve for x in sin^2(x) + tanx - 3/2 =0

Tags: trigonometry

original question: Is it possible to solve for x in   $$\sin^2x + \tan x  + \frac{3}{2} = 0 .$$

please show steps

edit:
sorry for typo mistake, the equation should be
$$\sin^2x + \tan x  - \frac{3}{2} = 0 .$$

Comment: It is possible. Notice sin^2(x) is always positive, so tan(x) must be negative ... What does that say about the quadrant(s) the answer lies in?

Comment: sorry, there`s typo mistake

Comment: Since now tan(x) must always be positive, that moves us into different quadrants(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sin^2x + \tan x - \frac 32 &= 0\\
\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x} + \tan x - \frac32 &= 0\\
2\tan^2x + (2\tan x) (1+\tan^2x) - 3(1+\tan^2x) &= 0 &&(1+\tan^2x \ne 0)
\end{align*}$$

This will be a cubic equation in $\tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for an existence proof, try using the Intermediate Value Theorem. As Ron Jensen suggested, since the function $\sin^2(x) + 3/2$ has range $[0,5/2]$, you need the following two things:

1. A value $x$ such that $\tan(x)< 0$.
2. A value $y$ such that $\tan(y)>5/2$.

If this is true, then there must be a value $z$ between $x$ and $y$ at which your function is equal to $0$.

For example, $x = -\pi/4$ and $y=1.2$ should suffice for the proof.

For example, you could

Comment: $\sin^2(x) + 3/2$ does not have range $[0,5/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @peterwhy's answer, let $t=\tan(x)$ and we need to solve the cubic equation $$2 t^3-t^2+2 t-3=0$$ but $t=1$ is an obvious solution. So
$$2 t^3-t^2+2 t-3=t-1) \left(2 t^2+t+3\right)$$ and the quadratic does not show any real root.